# Django 1.11 - Adding Permissions to existing users in production

Tags: django, django-models

## Problem

I have a database in production with users and I'm creating new permissions in some models. Now I need to add these permissions to some users depending on a condition. How should I do this? Should I add code to the migration to check all users and add permissions to them accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [DataMigration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

This allow you to run your regular migrations and then apply some logic (preferablly using a python code) to do some changes in your DB records.

Example:

```
from django.db import migrations, models

def my_data_migration_code(apps, schema_editor):
    my_model = apps.get_model('your_app', 'MyModel')
    for instance in my_model.objects.all():
        instance.name = instance.name + ' wow'
        instance.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
dependencies = [
    ('your_app', '0050_auto_20190207_1156'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='MyModel',
        name='blabla',
        field=models.BooleanField(default=True),
    ),
    migrations.RunPython(my_data_migration_code)
]
```

Comment: This is the way to do it if you want to apply one or more migrations and change the existing records in the DB before/after the migration